# Macro for arrow with a name using tikz

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

The following macro produces an arrow with a name between two objects. It has three parameters.

```
\newcommand{\rname}[3]{
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            {#1} \arrow[r, "{#2}"] \& {#3}
        \end{tikzcd}
    }
```

However, I would like to have only one parameter, the name of the arrow:

```
\newcommand{\rname}[1]{
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
              \arrow[r, "{#1}"] \& 
        \end{tikzcd}
    }
```

But this does not work with tikz. How can I fix it? Here is a compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\rname}[3]{
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        {#1} \arrow[r, "{#2}"] \& {#3}
    \end{tikzcd}
}

\begin{document}
    $\rname{A}{f}{B}$
   %$A\rname{f}B$ I would like it to function like this.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example

Answer (score 1):

Your one-parameter attempt nearly works, you'll just need to make sure that the cells aren't completely empty, e.g. an empty `{}` will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\rname}[1]{
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        \arrow[r, "{#1}"] \& {}
    \end{tikzcd}
}

\begin{document}
    $A\rname{f}B$
\end{document}
```

However if you just want to add some text above the arrow, using `tikzcd` seems a bit overkill. I would suggest something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rname}[1]{
    \xrightarrow{~~#1~~}
}

\begin{document}
    $A\rname{f}B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I do it like this, then there are extra spaces between the letters and the arrow. How can I remove these?

Comment: @Shimrod The extra space is because your A and B are not part of the tikzcd. That's a consequence of the one parameter syntax you wanted. If you want correct spacing, use the 3 parameter macro.

Comment: Ok, I will use that. Thank you.

Comment: @Shimrod Please see my edit, I suggested a second, much simpler solution

Comment: That's great! Finally I know how to add spacing to the \xrightarrow with a name so that it has correct length. Thank you!